# How do I bring the xticks in an uneven plot to show correctly?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[Uneven plot in the x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxyl6.png)

I am trying to plot using matplotlib an uneven plot in the x-axis. But the x-ticks are not showing in the correct place. Here is the python code of the image I uploaded. The x-ticks are showing in the bottom left of the image instead of under each data point.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

ticks = [0.0369, 11.58, 13.41, 13.78, 15.2609, 24.9, 26.7, 61.65]
xi = list(range(len(ticks)))

rmse_before_without_cm = ([0, 5.6290,  6.5244, 7.7890, 6.0990, 11.1103, 20.1758, 30.4631])
std_error_rmse_before_without_cm = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0,  0,  0, 0, 0])

rmse_before_with_cm = np.array([0, 4.4034, 4.4712, 3.7395,  3.7687, 7.2956, 2.8387, 19.4628])
std_error_rmse_before_with_cm = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

X_max = 62 
X_var = ticks
L = len(X_var) # number of x values

Y_var_1 = rmse_before_without_cm 
Y_var_err1 = std_error_rmse_before_without_cm 

Y_var_2 = rmse_before_with_cm 
Y_var_err2 = std_error_rmse_before_with_cm

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [6.4, 4.8]
plt.rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 2


plt.errorbar(X_var,Y_var_1,Y_var_err1,linestyle='None',markersize = 8,\
             marker = '+', capsize = 2, color = 'magenta', label = 'RMSE Before without Joined Cloud Mask')

plt.errorbar(X_var,Y_var_2,Y_var_err2,linestyle='None',markersize = 8,\
             marker = '^', capsize = 2, color = 'black', label = 'RMSE Before with Joined Cloud Mask')

FS = 18 
FS2 = 16
plt.xlabel('Cloud Cover $\%$', size=FS)
plt.ylabel('RMSE', size=FS)
plt.title('RMSE vs Cloud Cover $\%$', size=FS)

plt.yticks(fontsize = FS - 2) 
plt.xticks(xi, ticks)
plt.legend(fontsize = FS2-2) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: you should do plt.xticks(ticks) instead of plt.xticks(xi, ticks) see the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) probably you will need to add also plt.xticks(ticks, rotation=45) for the ticks to not overlap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `plt.xticks(xi, ticks)` to `plt.xticks(ticks)`

You might want to format the font etc. to get something readable.

[image]

Comment: Juat what I needed! I also modified the plot to make it more readable :)